# My idea for using activated carbon in the garden

Tags: fertilizer, soil-amendment

I have a 20 liter bucket of liquid fertiliser. I mixed some grass clippings and some twigs and branches and added saltpetre, gypsum, and epsom salts to it.

I must say I was surprised at how terrible the smell actually became. I thought it was going like wet earth and decaying plant matter but it really just smelled like sewage.

This bucket has been happily festering away for nearly a year. I was wondering if I bought some activated carbon and mix a water solution with this liquid fertiliser and till this into the soil in preparation for sowing if that would do anything?

Comment: You left out used coffee grinds and crushed egg shells. But why not just dilute and water the soil as is?

Comment: I thought the porous nature of the carbon would slow release the nutrients into the soil over a long time.

Comment: Is there anything else in the liquid other than the grass clippings, twigs, branches, saltpetre, gypsum, and epsom salts?

Comment: What kind of soil would you be tilling the carbon into?  Sandy?  Clay?

Comment: 1. Gypsum can harm non-ag soils: https://s3.wp.wsu.edu/uploads/sites/403/2015/03/gypsum.pdf.
2. Epsom salts are useless and/or can harm non-ag soils: https://s3.wp.wsu.edu/uploads/sites/403/2015/03/epsom-salts.pdf
3. Get a soil test before you do anything to your soil.
4. Charcoal is at best a useless add-in, which is why it's not in commercial fertilizers.
5. Go here: https://puyallup.wsu.edu/lcs/ and read all of the white papers on the site.

Comment: @Jurp There are 78 PDFs at that link, surely you can't be serious?

Comment: @Jurp, you should make it an answer